# Open Windows Explorer (WebDAV) from WebBrowser-Control fails

Tags: wpf, webbrowser-control, webdav

It's easy to reproduce this problem using a simple html fragment (save as test.html):

```
<style>
    a { behavior: url(#default#AnchorClick); }
</style>
<a href="https://webdav.mc.gmx.net/" folder="https://webdav.mc.gmx.net/" target="_blank">open</a>
```

If you open test.html in InternetExplorer and click on the open link, a new windows explorer pops up with the specified WebDAV folder. This is exactly what I expect.

Now if I open test.html inside the WPF WebBrowser-Control, the behavior is different. It opens a new Internet Explorer Window, showing a HTTP 405 error.

Here is the XAML and Code-Behind to test it in WPF WebBrowser:

```
<Window x:Class="Misc.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <WebBrowser x:Name="_browser" />
```

```
using System.IO;

namespace Misc
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            var file = Path.Combine(folder, "test.html");
            _browser.Navigate(file);
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE:

- In both cases, because it is a local file, you need to "Allow Blocked Content" first (yellow bar at top).
- The URL in this sample isn't the real one, because it is accessible on the intranet only. The real URL points at a SharePoint WebDAV Folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: One of the Hotfixes in SP1 fixed this issue. Don't know which one exactly, but here is the complete List:

- http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=269